# Unable to run a simple java file in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

File name - TestBase
File code -

```
public class TestBase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
}
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Initialization script 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\TestBase_main__.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:TestBase.main()'.
> SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 367ms

Comment: Android apps do not have a `main()` method. If you are trying to build a desktop Java program, please consider using IntelliJ IDEA, rather than Android Studio.